# FOR... DO in batch with multiples outputs

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create an output file; each line of the output file needs to contain the results from a program (few special characters) plus an explanatory plain string right after, but I'm not able to have a proper output. I'm sure it's something simple, but I just don’t have a lot of experience with cmd.

The first FOR creates the special output from my program (kind of a "#34FF123x" string, it's a barcode program). The second FOR is just an ECHO of the numbers that generated the special string. Of course, with two separate FORs I'm gonna have two separate groups on characters, I put them here just for explanation. Thanks for proposing any solution. The results may be also on two different lines, like alternating one from the Program and the next one being the string that generated the previous one. Cheers.

FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,5) DO Program %%G  >> output.file.txt

FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO ECHO %%i  >> output.file.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
> outputfile.txt (
    for /l %%i in (1 1 5) do (
        for /f "delims=" %%a in ('program %%i') do echo %%a %%i
    )
)
```

Probably the easiest way to have both values in the same line is to process the output of the `program` using a `for /f` command (that will retrieve the *"string"* into the replaceable parameter) and then `echo` the retrieved value and the current index.

Comment: Excellent solution, giving the correct output. Way above my experience with cmd, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `FOR` command is not fully documented; I've not been able to find any formal reference (just lots of sample code) for the grouping of the commands, nor have I been able to find a way to suppress any EOLs in output, but you can combine commands - and in this case, get alternating lines from the `program` and the `echo`:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do (
    program %%i >> output.file.txt
    echo %%i >> output.file.txt
)
```

If `program n` outputs `this is n`, then after running this, the contents of `output.file.txt` should be

```
this is 1
1
this is 2
2
this is 3
3
this is 4
4
this is 5
5
```

which is not *quite* what you've indicated you'd prefer, but seems to match what you'd said is acceptable.

Comment: If any answer supplied solves your problem, please remember to accept it (click the checkmark under the arrows to the left of the answer).